# Why can matrices be reversed when implementing the hypothesis function?

Tags: matrices, machine-learning

I'm learning about the hypothesis function used in linear regression.

$$h(\theta) = \theta_0X_0 + \theta_1X_1$$

Where $\theta$ is a $1\times 2$ matrix and $X$ is a $n\times 2$ matrix (with the first column of $X$ all 1's so it fits $\theta$).

I found an example [online](https://github.com/cnauroth/machine-learning-class/blob/master/ex1/computeCost.m) that instead of doing $\theta^TX$ does $X\theta^T$. Not only does that work but $\theta^T X$ can't be multiplied anyhow.

But in the [definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvIPD.png) that is exactly what they do. But matrix multiplication isn't transitive. So how is it that $X\theta^T$ is the correct answer when $\theta^T X$ is the definition?

Comment: I suspect that the definition you saw was using row vectors, so $X$ was $2\times n$ instead of $n\times 2$, and $\theta$ was $2\times 1$ instead. I'm not really familiar with this stuff, but that would seem like the most likely explanation to me.

Comment: Also, I don't think transitive is the word you are looking for. Maybe commutativity($AB = BA$)?

Comment: jgon, the rows in x represent the training sets so, i think, rows shoudl definitely be n. I think what they're doing is multipying scalars using a matrix not multiplying two matrices. ...i think

Comment: Asvin, yep, you are right. That is what I meant.